# How to hide the pricelist dropdown button to users that are not logged in?

Tags: odoo-16

I've been trying to make the price-list dropdown option not show the user if not logged in and once signed in, only show the price list it has been given without having the option to select the public price list.

In terms of the price list showing once logged in, the main issue is that it's very inconsistent. At times it shows only the price list that it has been assigned to and other times, they have the option to select the public price list.

The main problem is the hide the price list dropdown for the website to not logged in users.

I've tried modifying it in the HTML and CSS editor but it does not stay permanent.

Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to the html of the element that you wanna hide when the user it's not logged in:

```xml
<div t-if="not request.env.user._is_public()">
   ...
   price-list dropdown
   ...
</div>
```